# Multiple Sticky Items stacked

Tags: php, css, position, sticky, portfolio

I am creating a website and having some trouble.

The website is [test.scorpiontv.com](http://test.scorpiontv.com). So far we have the main navigation menu which is sticky, as per the theme ([Reel by WPZoom](http://demo.wpzoom.com/?theme=reel)). I want to make the "Our Programmes" sorting category bar sticky also, so that once we scroll down the categories remain visible (but the site's main navigation remains visible too). I have tried fiddling around with the code but nothing seemed to work. I would really appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

This is the code for the Portfolio sorting effect:

```
<div class="inner-wrap">

    <section class="portfolio-archive">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <section class="home_section">

                <?php the_title( '<h2 class="section-title">', '</h2>' ); ?>

                <div class="entry-header-excerpt"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

                <nav class="portfolio-archive-taxonomies">
                    <ul class="portfolio-taxonomies portfolio-taxonomies-filter-by">
                        <li class="cat-item cat-item-all current-cat"><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( option::get( 'portfolio_url' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'All', 'wpzoom' ); ?></a></li>

                        <?php wp_list_categories( array( 'title_li' => '', 'hierarchical' => true,  'taxonomy' => 'portfolio', 'depth' => 1 ) ); ?>
                    </ul>

                </nav>

            </section>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>


        <?php
        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'portfolio_item',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );

        $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        $col_number = option::get('portfolio_grid_col');

        ?>

        <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <div class="portfolio-grid col_no_<?php echo $col_number; ?>">

                <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'portfolio/content' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

            </div>

            <?php get_template_part( 'pagination' ); ?>

        <?php else: ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </section><!-- .portfolio-archive -->

</div>
```

This is the code for the main page where you see the portfolio:

```
 <?php if ( option::is_on( 'featured_posts_show' ) ) : ?>

    <div class="slider-wrap">

        <?php get_template_part( 'wpzoom-slider' ); ?>

    </div>

 <?php endif; ?>

 <div class="inner-wrap">

    <section class="portfolio-archive">

        <section class="home_section">

            <h2 class="section-title"><?php _e('Our Programmes', 'wpzoom'); ?></h2>

            <nav class="portfolio-archive-taxonomies" >
                 <ul class="portfolio-taxonomies portfolio-taxonomies-filter-by">
                     <li class="cat-item cat-item-all current-cat"><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( option::get( 'portfolio_url' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'All', 'wpzoom' ); ?></a></li>

                     <?php wp_list_categories( array( 'title_li' => '', 'hierarchical' => true,  'taxonomy' => 'portfolio', 'depth' => 1 ) ); ?>
                </ul>

            </nav>

        </section>


             <?php
             $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

             $args = array(
                 'post_type'      => 'portfolio_item',
                 'posts_per_page' => -1,
             );

             $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

             $col_number = option::get('portfolio_grid_col');

             ?>

             <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

                <div class="portfolio-grid col_no_<?php echo $col_number; ?>">

                     <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

                         <?php get_template_part( 'portfolio/content' ); ?>

                     <?php endwhile; ?>

                 </div>

                 <?php get_template_part( 'pagination' ); ?>

             <?php else: ?>

                 <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>

             <?php endif;

             wp_reset_query();
             ?>


     </section><!-- .portfolio-archive -->

 </div>
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve] working example, most people are not going to visit your site to troubleshoot your code. your SO post should include everything needed to replicate the issues trying to be resolved in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of Reel theme you're using.

Here is the solution for you:

Add the following PHP code (via a plugin like My Custom Functions) or child theme and CSS:

```css
@media (min-width: 980px) {

    .filter-not-top {
        position: fixed;
        top: 80px;
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
        background: #fff;
        height: 55px;
        z-index: 100;
        padding-top: 10px !important;
    }
}
```

```html
    function reel_fix_categories(){
    ?>
    <script>

        (function ($) {
            'use strict';

            var $document = $(document);
            var $window = $(window);

            $(function() {
                var header = $(".portfolio-archive-taxonomies");
                $(window).scroll(function() {
                    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

                    if (scroll >= 950) {
                        header.removeClass('clearHeader').addClass("filter-not-top");
                    } else {
                        header.removeClass("filter-not-top").addClass('clearHeader');
                    }
                });
            });

        })(jQuery);

    </script>
    <?php
    }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'reel_fix_categories');
```

You can see the result in this video: http://jmp.sh/U6bqXoA

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's excellent.

I have made a child theme and added the code but it does not seem to be responding. Do you know why that could be?

Thanks!

Comment: @BenHaines maybe you want to contact me via email instead? Or write directly in the contact form from our website.

Comment: Hi Pavel, sorry yes could I take your email instead. I have a couple of other questions too so it would be easier.